# Java NIO ByteBuffer: put and get strings

Tags: java

I've the following test code. I'd like to know how I can put, and get a String using a Java NIO ByteBuffer. 
I've added two comments where I need help.

```
package testPipe;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;

public class TestMemBuff {

    static final String dataFile = "invoicedata";
    static final double[] prices = { 19.99, 9.99, 15.99, 3.99, 4.99 };
    static final int[] units = { 12, 8, 13, 29, 50 };
    static final String[] descs = { "Java T-shirt", "Java Mug",
            "Duke Juggling Dolls", "Java Pin", "Java Key Chain" };

    public static Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    public static CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
    public static CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        double price;
        int unit;
        String desc;
        double total = 0.0;

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);


        for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            buf.putDouble(prices[i]);
            buf.putInt(units[i]);
            buf.asCharBuffer().put(descs[i]);           // Is it correct?
        }

        buf.flip();

        // INPUT
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {

            price = buf.getDouble();
            unit = buf.getInt();
            desc =  buf.asCharBuffer().toString();       //This must be wrong!
            System.out.format("You ordered %d" + " units of %s at $%.2f%n",
                    unit, desc, price);
            total += unit * price;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the output when I execute it:

```
You ordered 12 units of ????
[...]
```

and so on.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Does it really print `????` ? What does `toString` do?

Comment: Yes. There must be something wrong with encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    buf.putDouble(prices[i]);
    buf.putInt(units[i]);

    byte[] descsBytes = descs[i].getBytes();
    buf.putInt(descsBytes.length);
    buf.put(descsBytes);
}
```

Reading part:

```
while (buf.hasRemaining()) {

    price = buf.getDouble();
    unit = buf.getInt();

    int len = buf.getInt();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len]; 
    buf.get(bytes);
    desc = new String(bytes);

    System.out.format("You ordered %d" + " units of %s at $%.2f%n",
                unit, desc, price);
    total += unit * price;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Could you tell me how to use ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer() properly? What was wrong with my approach?

Comment: `asCharBuffer` will create only the view of the `ByteBuffer`, whose position value will be independent of the original buffer. So, while writing the buffer in 2nd iteration, string bytes were getting overwritten by the `double` value, then `int` and so on...Please ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asCharBuffer()

BTW, if you are certain about the max length of the `descs[i]`, you can pre-allocate `byte[] bytes` to avoid `new` operator in the read loop.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Greeat answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer()` has a somewhat own behaviour. It creates a new buffer that shares the content with the ByteBuffer but has an own, independent position & limit.
So put() and get() on the CharBuffer do not change the position on the ByteBuffer!

So I would refrain from using `ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer()` at all as long as this is not exactly what you need.

So the solution would be to write and read the bytes into the original ByteBuffer:

```
buf.putInt(descs[i].length);
buf.put(descs[i].getBytes());`
```

To read the string again read the length and allocate the byte[] yourself:

```
int stringLength = buf.getInt();
byte[] bytes = new byte[stringLength];
buf.get(bytes);
desc = new String(bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get errors:
You ordered 12 units of ????  

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
 at java.nio.CharBuffer.get(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.CharBuffer.get(Unknown Source)
 at testPipe.TestMemBuff.main(TestMemBuff.java:48)